# Systemd error "Timed out waiting for device dev-sdl2.device"

Tags: logging, hard-drive, systemd

I'm getting this error showing up in my logs.

```
Sep 19 23:50:24 MY-SERV systemd[1]: dev-sdj2.device: Job dev-sdj2.device/start timed out.
Sep 19 23:50:24 MY-SERV systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-sdj2.device.
Sep 19 23:50:24 MY-SERV systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/sdj2.
Sep 19 23:50:24 MY-SERV systemd[1]: dev-sdj2.swap: Job dev-sdj2.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 19 23:50:24 MY-SERV systemd[1]: dev-sdj2.device: Job dev-sdj2.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

```
$> ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda   /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdd1  /dev/sdf1  /dev/sdh1  /dev/sdj1  /dev/sdl1
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdc   /dev/sde   /dev/sdg   /dev/sdi   /dev/sdk   /dev/sdm
/dev/sda2  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sde1  /dev/sdg1  /dev/sdi1  /dev/sdk1  /dev/sdm1
/dev/sdb   /dev/sdd   /dev/sdf   /dev/sdh   /dev/sdj   /dev/sdl
```

not a /dev/sd*2 in sight, apart from my 'sda2' which is my boot SSD.

Currently, my logfile is 800K and growing with each minute.

Info: 18.04.3, Kernel 5.0.0-29-generic

I'm running GlusterFS on this machine with great successes. I like it over a conventional raid that if a disk fails I can still retrieve the files manually from the disk rather than just 1's and 0's on a platter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system is trying to activate swap on a device partition `/dev/sdj2`, which is not present. Check `/etc/fstab` to see what swap partitions have been defined, and make any necessary corrections. Once this file is fixed, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to cause systemd to re-read it.

Comment: They weren't there last week. Thanks, worked perfectly!